# Can not get Sringboot app to see my ReactJS app

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I built a UI in React locally (localhost:3000), and built a production app. Now I have to create a WAR file to put into the server, so I created a very simple web app in Springboot. But, my controller is not picked up my .jsp (or .html - doesn't matter what I have it set to.)

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
      @RequestMapping("/")
      public String hello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello from the controller");
        return "mainApp";
      }
}
```

Sring Boot App

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebappApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Application Props.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.port=8090
```

Folders:

[image]

POM File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <groupId>---</groupId>
    <artifactId>---</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>UI</name>

    <description>--</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AOP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Common DBCP2 connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HttpClient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>  
    </build>
</project>
```

I get the following

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Feb 18 10:12:13 EST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: Are you actually *using* ReactJS **and** JSPs? Or do you just want to serve the React app and try to do it via a JSP?

Comment: I had it as a HTML document prior... then i changed it to a jsp to see if that was the problem. im not well verse in springboot...so, to answer your question, it was a.... try to make it work via jsp. the application in build in reactjs... so yes i am using react. when you build it for production, you get the files i show in the image.